# can't install Gdal on centos7

Tags: python-2.7, centos7, yum, gdal

Hello everyone and thanks for your help.

My problem is I am trying to install GDAL on CENTOS7, using yum I achieve to do it but on pyhton2.7 doesn't recognize it.

using yum, it install the version 1.11.4-1.el7  from EPEL repo
but when using PIP LIST, doesn't appear as installed.

when trying to do it again with pip it show this error:

```
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:3085:22: error fatal: cpl_port.h: No existe el      fichero o el directorio
(is is spanish: "directory doesn't exit")
#include "cpl_port.h"
                    ^
compilación terminada.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

 ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for gdal
```

I think pip is trying to install the newest version but Centos accepts only up to v1.11.4

please help me to install it correctly U_U

Answer (score 0):

gdal library files are in the */usr/include/gdal* path, therefor you need to add them to the path.
please try 

`echo $'export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal\nexport \
C_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH' >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile
...`